# Can Gmail Add-Ons always remain displayed without email message?

Tags: google-apps-script

Can [Gmail Add-ons](https://developers.google.com/gmail/add-ons) be defined in a way that a Card or a Widget be displayed *before* you click on an individual email message?  I can't find any examples where this can be done so I'm not sure if this is even possible.

I thought [Universal Actions](https://developers.google.com/gmail/add-ons/how-tos/universal-actions) would do the trick, but `gmail.universalActions` are just actions that does not depend on the current email context.

I'm trying to develop a dashboard mini-app that lives inside of the gmail app, which does not depend on the current email context.  **It should be always on**, and shouldn't be activated when someone clicks on an individual email message.

Answer (score 0):

I would have thought you would need to use a Chrome Extension or something like InboxSDK.

That approach though will limit you to "Gmail in Chrome" only.